# Scroll a specific element when scrolling the entire window

Tags: jquery, scroll

Here's my code:

```
$(body).scroll(function() {
        $('#page_text').scroll();
    });
```

As you can see I'm pretty poorly trying to scroll #page_text while scrolling on the rest of the page. The website has very specific dimension to adapt to the size of the screen, so #page_text is overflow:auto... for a question of style i needed to hide the scrollbar of the site. I hope I've explained myself, thanks to everyone who wants to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('scroll', function() {
      var docScrollHeight = $(this).scrollTop();
      $('#page_text').scrollTop(docScrollHeight);
   });
});
```

This will call the function on every document scroll and will find the current documents scroll height. It will then scroll the `page_text` element to the same scroll height.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really a beginner, so I understand how your code works on paper, but maybe i have some major problems in the structure of the site. Anyway, I'll explain you.

the real problem is that the document per se doesen't scroll, because the site is meant to be wiewed completely in a screen, and all the content is scrolled in page_text... so i think that scrolltop always gets 0 as value.

Comment: Is it possible for you to link to your site, or try and create a test example somewhere? i.e. [JSFiddle](http://JSFiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VjnYP/

I hope this gives the idea. I want to scroll the area of text by acting on the body.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help me much, can you explain what you mean by "Acting on the body"?

Comment: If i scroll with the mousewheel on the body, i need that the area with the text scrolls too, even if the body can't scroll because it doesn't overflow the visible screen